# Nested Sabermetric SQL - Average Plate appearances and Games

Tags: sql

I am trying to find the average games and average plat appearances for the MLB over the 2012 season for outfielders ORDERED BY their birthYear.   Currently, this SQL shows entries for each player. The database is the lahman database
 http://seanlahman.com/files/database/readme2012.txt

I get the error:

```
MySQL Error 1248: Every derived table must have its own alias
```

Does anyone see the problem.  It is most definitely in the way I nested the selects, but I am not sure where.

```
   SELECT AVG(PA) AS AVG_PA, AVG(b.G) AS AVG_G
        FROM(
        SELECT CONCAT(m.nameFirst, ' ', m.nameLast) AS playerName, m.birthYear, f.pos, b.yearID, b.teamID, b.stint,
          b.G,
          (b.AB+b.BB+b.HBP+b.SF+b.SH) AS PA
        FROM Batting b
        JOIN Master m
          ON b.playerID = m.playerID
        JOIN Fielding f
         ON f.playerID = b.playerID
          AND f.yearID = b.yearID
          AND f.stint = b.stint
        WHERE  (f.POS = 'LF'AND b.yearID = '2013') 
            OR (f.POS = 'CF' AND b.yearID = '2013')
            OR (f.POS = 'RF' AND b.yearID = '2013')
    )
    ORDER BY m.birthYear
```

Thanks

Comment: did the answer solve your problem?

Comment: Hey @RADAR, your solution worked to find the averages.  However, my logic was wrong.  I want to find batting statistics for individual outfielders.  However, many outfielders played the different outfield postions ("RF","CF", and "LF"). Thus, the issue is that since, I alias the batting table and search by fielding position, I get several repeat rows per player and it messes up the average.  I need to figure out how to get distinct cases, so player id's or names aren't repeated once it has found they played the outfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subquery needs a `ALIAS` name

in the outer SELECT you need to access the columns using table alias name given to the subquery.

```
SELECT AVG(T.PA) AS AVG_PA, AVG(T.G) AS AVG_G
        FROM(
        SELECT CONCAT(m.nameFirst, ' ', m.nameLast) AS playerName, m.birthYear, f.pos, b.yearID, b.teamID, b.stint,
          b.G,
          (b.AB+b.BB+b.HBP+b.SF+b.SH) AS PA
        FROM Batting b
        JOIN Master m
          ON b.playerID = m.playerID
        JOIN Fielding f
         ON f.playerID = b.playerID
          AND f.yearID = b.yearID
          AND f.stint = b.stint
        WHERE  (f.POS = 'LF'AND b.yearID = '2013') 
            OR (f.POS = 'CF' AND b.yearID = '2013')
            OR (f.POS = 'RF' AND b.yearID = '2013')
    ) T
    ORDER BY T.birthYear
```